# How do I append label to image as input for Conditional VAE?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, autoencoder

The rank is just not the same: [?, 28, 28, 1] and [?, 10]. How should I deal with this

Answer (score 0):

Just reshape your `[?, 28, 28, 1]` tensor into `[?, 28*28*1]` and concatenate it with `[?, 10]` at `axis=1`, so you'll have a new tensor of shape `[?, (28*28*1 + 10)]` then you can use CVAE as usual.